# Disallow automatic updates

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, update, nokia-lumia-930

This night my phone restarted automatically to install updates, what meant that I lost all phone connectivity untill I woke up and inserted the SIM PIN code...

This is really really bad, I could of had an emergency call during the night and I would not receive it..

How can I disable automatic updates?

I read this:

> The easiest way to prevent Windows 10 from automatically downloading updates is to use a metered Internet connection -- one of the features of limiting your data is that Windows 10 won't force-download OS updates. Some networks, such as cell networks, are metered by default, but you can also meter your Wi-Fi network by going to Settings > Network & Internet > Wi-Fi > Advanced options and turning Set metered connection on. [Source](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/stop-windows-10-from-automatically-updating-your-pc/)

But I couldn't find the option, is it available on WM? is there any other way?

**P.S.:** Removing the SIM PIN code is not an option..

Answer (score 1):

If you turn off Wifi the phone will switch to your the metered connection provided through your SIM card. This should prevent OS update downloads. 
You can also change the active hours to prevent restarts or you set a custom restart time if there's already a restart scheduled.

Comment: The problem is that the phone makes the download during the day and does the update during the non active hours, if you pass to a metered connection during the night it won't prevent the update, since the download was already made...

Comment: Changing the active hours was a great idea, I did that a couple of months ago, so that the non active hours would be during the morning when I was at work... but after the update the active hours changed automatically. I think Windows is able to perceive the active hours automatically and adjust itself... Maybe the solution is to do it everytime after an update..

Comment: I hope you won't need to adjust the active hours after every update. What would be the reason to let you adjust it then if they know better ;-)
AFAIK the creators update will bring more options to control OS updates - maybe this will improve for mobile as well.